# Django Query multiple tables

Tags: django-models, django-orm

I have a user model which stores user information
A follow model to store who is following whom
A activity model that stores activities of users. 
Now i want to develop news feed for a user, feeds will contain activities of only those users who that logged in user is following. 
Help with the query how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want to create the news feed for "user_1" the following piece of code will do that for you:

```
Activities.objects.filter(user__in = user_1.following.all())
```